# How do you add a multi-line description to markers in a react map?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I am developing a react native app which includes a react map and some markers where each has a description. Each description is too long to put on a single line, but when I try and make it a multiline string as so:

```
const description = `Info1: Data 
Info2: Data
Info3: Data`

return (
  <MapView.Marker
    key = {index}
    coordinate = {marker.coords}
    title = {marker.country}
    description = {description}
  />
)
```

the lower lines of the description are hidden and cannot be expanded:

[image]

How do I overide this and display all the information about the marker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for way to customize your [Callout](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/callout.md). You need to pass a custom Callout View to your Marker. See Example below.

**Code:**

```
<MapView 
       style={{top: 0, left:0 , bottom: 0, right: 0, position: 'absolute'}}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
       >
    <MapView.Marker 
    coordinate={{latitude: 37.78825, longitude: -122.4324 }}>
      <MapView.Callout>
        <View style={{height: 100, width: 200}}>
          <Text> Title </Text>
          <Text> Long Description    Even More Text</Text>
          <Text>Multline Description </Text>
        </View>
      </MapView.Callout>
    </MapView.Marker>
</MapView>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo:**

https://snack.expo.io/@tim1717/quiet-crackers